# Aframe Emitting Custom Events Between Components

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm trying to create a custom event `dataReady` in a-frame which will emit when a few different data sources have successfully downloaded. I would like for multiple other components to listen for this event and then cause their element parents to become visible or perform other actions.

In the sample code below, the `eventListener` is being added before the event is emitted (tested using `console.log()`), but the listener function on the element is not being called when the event is emitted. I feel like all the pieces are in place, but it just isn't working correctly. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated?

Component 1 attached to `<a-camera data-controller></a-camera>`

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('data-controller', {
    init: function () {
        var el = this.el;
    },
    update: function () {
        async.eachSeries(['api-1', 'api-2'],
            function (item, cb) {
                console.log(item);
                cb();
            },
            function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    throw new Error('Error retrieving data from server');
                }

                console.log("emitting the event");
                this.el.emit("dataReady", {value: 2}, false);
            }.bind(this));
    }
});
```

Component 2 attached to `<a-entity geometry="primitive:plane" road></a-entity>`

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('road', {
    schema: {
        width: {type: 'number', default: 4},
        height: {type: 'number', default: 4}
    },

    init: function () {
        var data = this.data;
        var el = this.el;

        // Update geometry props
        el.setAttribute('geometry', 'width', data.width);
        el.setAttribute('geometry', 'height', data.height);

        console.log('adding an event listener');
        el.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            console.log("we are ready to blast off b/c of event listened w/ detail value: " + event.detail.value);
        });
    }
});
```

index.html contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!--Vendor Scripts-->
    <script src="./js/vendor/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/vendor/async.min.js"></script>

    <!--AFRAME Components-->
    <script src="./js/components/road.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/data-controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a-scene>
    <a-entity geometry="primitive:plane" road></a-entity>
    <a-camera data-controller></a-camera>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could rely on the **event bubbling** and listen on the scene, and store the entity in the event detail so you know where it came from:

```
// data-controller component
this.el.emit('dataready', {value: 2, el: this.el})
// Event will bubble to the scene.

// road component
this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('dataready', function () { // ... });
```

Or you can pass a reference with the **selector property type** to which entity to want to listen to:

```
// road component
schema: {
    dataEl: {type: 'selector'},
    width: {type: 'number', default: 4},
    height: {type: 'number', default: 4}
},

init: function () {
  // ...
  this.data.dataEl.addEventListener('dataready', function () { // ... });
}

// <a-entity road="dataEl: [data-controller]"></a-entity>
```

Comment: thanks @ngokevin! I was disabling the bubbling by providing `false` as the third option in the `emit` function and then didn't know about `sceneEl`. Works great now. Thanks again for the fast response!

Comment: using the emit function is definitely the right way to go, however, I would advise using the standard target and currentTarget attributes on the event instead of passing the el in the details.
I create a fiddle to show how this works: https://jsfiddle.net/beyerz/1wrftbc6/

Comment: I'm trying this, but all I get on the listener is `{"isTrusted":false}`